# LINQ to SQL and nested EntitySet type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got a model which has an EntitySet.  I'm trying to build a LINQ statement but I'm not sure how to form the code.  I get a cast error because it can't convert a generic list to the EntitySet type.

```
select new ParentRecord {
ParentID = item.ParentID,
Name = item.Name,
Age = item.Age,
MyNestedChildRecords = (from ns in item.MyNestChildRecords
                       select ns).ToList();
}.ToList();
```

**Cannot convert source type "List" to target type "EntitySet"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you have something like

```
from item in myItems
select new ParentRecord {
....
```

The problem is that you can't simply convert a `List<T>` into an `EntitySet<T>` because `EntitySet<T>` doesn't have a suitable constructor.

The easiest way to do this is using LINQ fluent syntax with an anonymous method in the `Select`:

```
var result = myItems.Select(item => 
                {
                    var record = new ParentRecord
                    {
                        ParentID = item.ParentID,
                        Name = item.Name,
                        Age = item.Age
                    };
                    record.MyNestedChildRecords.AddRange(item.MyNestChildRecords);
                    return record;
                }).ToList()
```

I assume that `ParentRecord` is a LINQ-to-Sql entity class, so its `MyNestedChildRecords` will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var test = (from ns in item.MyNestedChildRecords
            select new ParentRecord
            {
                ParentID = item.ParentID,
                Name = item.Name,
                Age = item.Age,
                MyNestedChildRecords = new EntitySet<MyNestedChildRecords>() { ns }
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for that.  I have other fields which are in the select new.  So i'm not sure how your example would fit?  I'll update my example to include other fields :o)

Comment: Is your ParentRecord.MyNestedChildRecords property a type of List<MyNestChildRecords>() ?

Comment: Hiya, it's declared as an EntitySet in the parent class e.g private EntitySet<MyNestedChildRecords> _MyNestedChildRecords;

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm not sure it this is what you are trying to do but that is how you assign a list to a EntitySet.

Comment: Thanks James, I tried that and now I get: Argument type Devart.Data.Linq.EntitySet<MyNestedChildRecords>' is not assignable to parameter type 'MyNestedChildRecord'.  It's almost as if I'm trying to assign a list to something that can only take a single record if I'm reading the error right.  Incase it has any bearing I'm using: new EntitySet<MyNestedChildRecords>() { item.MyNestedChildRecords }